# from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS Как понять эту конструкцию?

Tags: python, python-3.x

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS`
Как понять эту конструкцию?

Comment: А причём тут конкретно эта библиотека? Читайте https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: `из bs4 импортировать BeautifulSoup как BS`. Слово "как" подразумевает создание синонима `BS` для имени `BeautifulSoup`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По-моему достаточно этот код перевести на русский как с английского:

> из bs4 импортировать BeautifulSoup как BS

Объясняю:

- Есть модуль `bs4`
- В нем есть объект `BeautifulSoup`
- Вы импортируете из модуля этот объект под именем `BS`

*Any questions?..*